# Equivariant cohomology of $\text{Diff}S^1/ S^1$ and Virasoro

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mp.mathematical-physics, topological-groups, kahler-manifolds, virasoro-algebra

Consider 
$$\mathcal{M}\ =\ \text{Diff}S^1/S^1$$
which is a contractible complex manifold with an action of $\text{Diff}S^1$ by translations. It is claimed in page 358 of [1] that $\mathcal{M}$ has single-dimensional equivariant cohomology $H^2_{\text{Diff}S^1}(\mathcal{M})$, which is related to the central charge in the Virasoro algebra.

> Question: is $H^*_{\text{Diff}S^1}(\mathcal{M})$ known in general, and what relation does it have to the Virasoro algebra?

I think the first part might be easy because (I think) the stack $\mathcal{M}/\text{Diff}S^1$ is homotopic to $B\text{Diff}S^1$, which in turn is homotopic to $B \text{U}(1)$ which has cohomology $\mathbf{Z}[x]$.

[1] M. Bowick, S. Rajeev: *The holomorphic geometry of closed bosonic string theory and $\text{Diff}S^1/S^1$*.

---

*Edit*: I should maybe explain what [1] says.  It says that the two-form $\text{Ric}$ (Ricci curvature) satisfies
$$\text{Ric}(L_m,L_n)\ =\ \left(\frac{-26}{12}m^3+\frac{1}{6}m\right) \delta_{-m,n}$$
where $L_n$ are the  vector fields on $\mathcal{M}$ generating the action of $\text{Diff}S^1$. It then goes on to make the relationship between the generator of $H^2$ and the central charge more precise (I've not read the paper closely but I don't think it contains an answer to my question).

Comment: because the inclusion $SO(2) \to \text{Diff}(S^1)$ is a homotopy equivalence and a homomorphism, $H^*_{\text{Diff}(S^1)} = H^*_{SO(2)}$. but because $\mathcal M$ is non-equivariantly contractible, the map $H^*_{SO(2)}(\mathcal M) \to H^*_{SO(2)}(pt)$ is an isomorphism, so that your cohomology is indeed $\Bbb Z[x]$, the cohomology of $BSO(2)$. (I do not know anything about Virasoro algebras, this is just a confirmation that the easy part of your question holds.)

Answer (score 5):

For any group $G$ and subgroup $K$, there is an isomorphism
$$
H^*_G(G/K)= H^*_K(pt)
$$

So the cohomology in question is $H^*_{S^1}(pt)=\mathbb Z[x]$, and it does not seem to be very related to the Virasoro algebra.
(Here, the generator $x\in H^2_{S^1}(pt)$ is in degree two.)

---

If I remember correctly, the Lie algebra cohomology of the Witt algebra (with coefficients in the trivial module $\mathbb C$) is a polynomial algebra generated by a class in degree $2$ tensor an exterior algebra generated by a class in degree $3$. From this, I think that one can deduce that the Lie algebra cohomology of the Virasoro algebra (= the universal central extension of the Witt algebra) is an exterior algebra generated by a class in degree $3$.